# sed command to beautify output of an awk command

Tags: sed, awk, cut

i have the following output from an awk command..i want to beautify output as follows..is there an sed command that will give me the expected output?

```
CURRENT OUTPUT:-
    https://code-comp.com/308271
                                (there is white space line here)   
    https://code-comp.com/308270
    466197
    https://code-comp.com/308263
    470188
    https://code-comp.com/308262
    https://code-comp.com/308261
```

Following is the expected output

```
    EXPECTED OUTPUT:-
    https://code-comp.com/308271
    https://code-comp.com/308270 466197
    https://code-comp.com/308263 470188
    https://code-comp.com/308262
    https://code-comp.com/308261
```

Comment: Posting the commands would help, wouldn't it?

Comment: Why don't you fix it in awk?

Comment: @awk '/link|issue-Fixed:/{print $2}' foo.txt | sed 'N; y/\n/ /' is the command

Comment: Please post the input file, you do **not** need to pipe `awk` to `sed` you need to alter your `awk` script to do the whole job. Also please confirm if you actually want leading TABS on every line or if that is a mistake of the formatting of the question. This will remove the blank lines at least `awk '/link|issue-Fixed:/&&$2{print $2}'` appending the digits to previous line will also be a trival fix but need to know the format of the input.

Comment: "I have an awk issue, how do I fix it with sed?". Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;/\nhttps:/!{s/\n/ /;ta};s/\s*(\n|$)/\1/;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sed 'N; /\n[0-9]/s/\n/ /; s/\n$//' foo.txt
```

- read in second line
- look for lines starting with number, merge those with previous line
- remove empty lines

Comment: @StevenPenny - can we make the newline optional...that is if the line start with a number merge to previousl line,not sure if this is the right approach..there are some numbers that are on a line but they are failing to merge back..is there crude way to check for a number on a line and force it back to merge on previous line

Comment: @Steven - does this look for second line or anyline that starts with a number and merges back to previous line,i thik that would be a good logic